# Why ave results in error in unique.default?

Tags: r

```
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 10)
ave(x, cut(x, 10), mean)
```

Why exactly this returns the following error?

> Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) :    unique() applies only to
>   vectors

`cut` returns a factor of the same length as `x` and according to `ave` documentation:

> ...   Grouping variables, typically factors, all of the same length as x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax for `ave` is

```
ave(x, ..., FUN = mean)
```

where `...` is

> Grouping variables, typically factors, all of the same length as x

which means you can have more than 1 grouping variable in `ave`. To apply the function in `ave`, you need to name the function with `FUN` explicitly.

Hence, do

```
ave(x, cut(x, 10), FUN = mean)
```

Moreover, the default function in `ave` is `mean`, so in this case you can directly do

```
ave(x, cut(x, 10))
```